# What are the pitfalls of using subjective ratings for correlation and causal explanation?

Tags: correlation, repeated-measures, dataset, normalization, bias

Take a study that collects subjective guesstimates as a proxy for some variable, like the quality of service. In a simplest model, we then regress the monthly sales on these guesstimates. How to interpret the results given that they originate from subjective estimations?

One problem is that respondents have no common anchor in many cases (as explained on [CogSci.SE](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/5168/how-do-people-perceive-subjective-scales)). This means that even if the relations between the quality of service and sales exist, they may not appear because of difference in understanding what "good" service is.

Let's take the extreme case when the sales and quality are the same across the sample, but each person rates the quality as he or she perceives it. Then we have a non-existing variation in the quality.

What are the techniques to normalize subjective scales? Kahneman and Tversky suggested the reference class model, in which you adjust the cognitive bias using a common class for calibration across the whole sample of experts. But it's not always feasible.

Comment: If objective data cannot be obtained, the expert opinions are feasible as long as they are independent.

Answer (score 2):

@chl and I have discussed some ideas for handling a somewhat related issue in [factor analysis of questionnaires composed of Likert items](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2374/32036). It sounds like you might be dealing with a Likert scale or something similar, where anchors are interpreted subjectively and responses are forced into discrete categories. Polychoric correlations or Goodman-Kruskal $\gamma$ / Kendall's $\tau$ (see [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/18112/32036) for help deciding) might be best in such situations, though with five or more categories, ordinal rating scales may approximate continuous intervals closely enough.

[chl's answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/2375/32036) discusses some other useful ideas like item response theory (IRT), latent class analysis (LCA), and [unfolding models](http://www.psychology.gatech.edu/unfolding/Intro.html). LCA can help identify respondents with particularly unusual response styles, and IRT can give a somewhat subtler sense of where even similar respondents might lie on the continuum of response style relative to one another, especially if they're estimating multiple common values like the relative qualities of a particular set of services. One could use $\theta$ estimates for particular individuals from an IRT analysis of their ratings of a criterion sample of services to predict differences in ratings of other, similar services. If those predictions hold reasonably well, the $\theta$ estimates would represent respondents' bias well enough to control for it if one wanted to.

If you trust your judges well enough to call them experts (or can't justify disregarding any oddball judges after performing LCA or otherwise assessing [inter-rater reliability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-rater_reliability)), it seems to me like the simplest solution is to estimate the central tendency of your judges' ratings by whatever means best suit their distributions, and take that as an estimate of the "true score." If that's not feasible (e.g., if you're not working with a set of expert judges and a criterion set suitable for reasonably objective bias estimation), and the other approaches listed here don't address the particular challenges you have in mind, you might want to narrow down the question by describing what specific limits or validity doubts apply to the information that you have.

Comment: @Anton If you trust your judges but not all of them and do not know whose opinion might be biased, you can use trimmed mean as a central tendency, such as in figure skating for that purpose.

Comment: Nick, you gave a very useful answer. To narrow the question, one issue is that the responses have one (or few) expert estimate per random variable, not multiple expert estimates of each random variable. And the estimates seemingly have upward bias in the lower quantiles. Experts estimating low-quality services tend to overestimate them because their basic anchor is lower than that of high-quality services.